# What is difference between "Hate" and "Detest"?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, word-difference

What is difference between ***hate*** and ***detest***?
and which word is stronger.

For example:

> 1. I **hate** you.
> 2. I **detest** you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using a dictionary as is always recommended firstly, shows no difference:

**[Hate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hate?q=HATE)**: to dislike someone or something very much:

**[Detest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/detest?q=DETEST)**: to hate someone or something very much:

But [this site](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/ecco/004892937.0001.001/1:7.4?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) suggests differences between the synonyms of hate as follow:

"**To Abhor, Hate, To Loath, Detest**: all these words imply aversion, but re|quire to be differently used, upon different occasions.

**To abhor**, implys an aversion to that, to which, we have a natural antipathy; **hate**, an aversion actuated by revenge: **loath**, is more applicable to food: **detest**, implies a|version actuated by disapprobation.

We **abhor**, what we cannot endure. We are apt to **hate** the person, who injures us. We **loath** the food, by which we have been surfeited. We **detest** the man, who is guilty of a mean action.

The spendthrift, naturally, **abhors** niggardliness, and the niggard, profligacy. The **hatred** of the revengeful man, is roused, whenever the object of his revenge approaches. The stomach **loaths** the very sight of that meat, by which we have been satiated. Every, thinking, man **detests** the least degree of meanness, more particularly that, which is fordid or base."

Answer (score 0):

I think **"detest"** is the strongest **"hate"**.
And by the way, **"detest"** is used much less often than **"hate"**.